# How would I transfer a number from one class to another in Java?

Tags: java, numbers

I'm trying to make a user inputed number that's in the main function appear in the second class that has all the function. And in the second class I'm trying to make that number useable in the whole class methods and functions

Class 1: (Main class/Function)

```
    System.out.println("How long is your number?: ");       
    int numberLength = keyboard.nextInt();
```

Class 2:

```
    private int[] lotteryNumbers = new int [3]; //3 is supposed to be numberLength
```

Any suggestions on how to do this? I'm a little lost.

Comment: Pass it as a parameter in your constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass your value as a parameter in your parameterized constructor. Note, in that case, you would need to provide both 0-arg and parameterized constructor, if you want to use 0-arg.

```
public class Class1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numberLength = keyboard.nextInt();
        Class2 obj = new Class2(numberLength);

    }
}

class Class2 {
    private int[] lotteryNumbers;

    public Class2() { }
    public Class2(int length) {
       lotteryNumbers = new int [length];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your other class has a method with parameter type int/long

You could simply instantiate other class and invoke method with number as parameter.

Example:

```
class B
{
public void otherClassMethod(int param)
{
//loigc
}
}

class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
B b = new B();
b.otherClassMethod(yourNumber);
}
}
```